# Sencha touch-how should I add a tab panel inside a panel? following answer is not working it not diaplaying content inside tab panel

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch

```
Ext.define('SenchaCalc.view.TabScreen',{
extend: 'Ext.tab.Panel',
xtype: 'tabScreen',
requires: [
    'Ext.tab.Panel',
],
config:{



        xtype:'tabpanel',   
        ui: 'light',
        itemId: 'tabPanel',
        name: 'tabPanel',
        layout: 
        {
            animation: 'fade',
            type: 'card'
        },

        items:[
        {
            title: 'HOME',
            iconCls: 'home',
            itemId:'home',


            items:[{
                    xtype:'panel',
                    itemId:'homePanel',
                    height:450,
                    width:1010,
                    items:[{

                                xtype:'button',
                                itemId:'homePanelButton',
                                name:'homePanelButton',
                                html:'I m in Home Panel',
                                height:50,
                                width:350,
                                style:'border:0px;background:#1985D0;',
                                cls:'homePanelButton',

                    }]
                        }]

                }]
        },
        {
            title: 'HELP',
            iconCls: 'action',
            itemId:'help',
            items:[{
                    xtype:'panel',
                    itemId:'helpPanel',
                    height:450,
                    width:1010,
                    items:[{

                                xtype:'button',
                                itemId:'helpPanelButton',
                                name:'helpPanelButton',
                                html:'I m in Help Panel',
                                height:50,
                                width:350,
                                style:'border:0px;background:#1985D0;',
                                cls:'helpPanelButton',

                    }]

                }]
        }],

}
});



   /******************************************************************************/


Ext.define('SenchaCalc.view.MainScreen',{
extend: 'Ext.Panel',
xtype: 'mainScreen',
requires: [
    'Ext.tab.Panel',
],
config:{

        xtype: 'panel',

    items:[
        xtype: 'tabScreen',
            ]

}
});
```

Answer (score 0):

How you are handling navigation between panel and tabscreen in your MainScreen? If you have any controller paste the code. You have not mentioned any layout there. If you want to present them in different screen then please use card layout for MainScreen. For testing of nested tabpanel inside panel I have used vbox layout and pasted the code here. Please run this on sencha jsfiddle for testing.

```
Ext.application({
name: 'Sencha',

launch: function() {
    Ext.create("Ext.Panel", {
        fullscreen: true,
        xtype: 'mainScreen',
        layout: {
            type: 'vbox'
        },
        requires: [
            'Ext.tab.Panel',
        ],
         items:[
            {
                xtype: 'panel',
                flex:1,
                style: 'background:red',
                html:'Main screen data'
            },
            {
                xtype: 'tabpanel',flex:1,
                tabBarPosition: 'bottom',

                defaults: {
                    styleHtmlContent: true
                },

                items: [
                    {
                        title: 'Page1',
                        iconCls: 'home',
                        html: 'Panel screen data page1'
                    },
                    {
                        title: 'Page2',
                        iconCls: 'user',
                        html: 'Panel screen data page2'
                    }
                ]
            }

         ]

        });
  }
```

});